# Which code lines of Activiti Explorer to edit model?

Tags: model, business-process-management, activiti

I now have plan to create new Activiti Explorer separated from Vaadin. Would you show me which code lines to edit model?. I have read source code and extract that method:

```
public String editModel(String modelID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RepositoryService repositoryService = ActivitiUtil
            .getRepositoryService();

    Model model = repositoryService.getModel(modelID);
    //
    SimpleWorkflowJsonConverter simpleWorkflowJsonConverter = new SimpleWorkflowJsonConverter();
    WorkflowDefinition workflowDefinition = simpleWorkflowJsonConverter
            .readWorkflowDefinition(repositoryService
                    .getModelEditorSource(model.getId()));
    WorkflowDefinitionConversionFactory workflowDefinitionConversionFactory = new WorkflowDefinitionConversionFactory();

    WorkflowDefinitionConversion conversion = workflowDefinitionConversionFactory
            .createWorkflowDefinitionConversion(workflowDefinition);
    conversion.convert();

    model.setCategory(null);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode metaInfoJson = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
    metaInfoJson.put("name", model.getName());
    model.setMetaInfo(metaInfoJson.toString());
    repositoryService.saveModel(model);

    BpmnJsonConverter bpmnJsonConverter = new BpmnJsonConverter();
    ObjectNode json = bpmnJsonConverter.convertToJson(conversion
            .getBpmnModel());
    try {
        repositoryService.addModelEditorSource(model.getId(), json
                .toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return model.getId();
}
```

However, I got this error:

org.activiti.workflow.simple.exception.SimpleWorkflowException: Error while parsing JSON
    at org.activiti.workflow.simple.converter.json.SimpleWorkflowJsonConverter.wrapExceptionRead(SimpleWorkflowJsonConverter.java:107)
    at org.activiti.workflow.simple.converter.json.SimpleWorkflowJsonConverter.readWorkflowDefinition(SimpleWorkflowJsonConverter.java:69)

How do I fix those codes?
Thank you very much

Comment: Hi all, I already found my mistake. You can read more in this link <link>http://forums.activiti.org/content/which-code-lines-activiti-explorer-edit-model</link>. How to edit model, well, simply, in your webapp, just import Activiti-Rest and redirect to the correct url